# starting wlan0 as default for accessing internet

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, wifi

I was using Wlan0 but in the middle I do not know where I messed up wlan0 wasn't starting automatically instead my pi3 was trying to connect through ethernet with LAN cable plugged in, so I unplugged LAN cable it was still not having wlan0 started automatically so I have put this below line in `/etc/rc.local`

`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart; sudo ifup wlan0`

Is it ok to put in `/etc/rc.local` I am doubting because earlier it used to start automatically without this line in `rc.local`?

Contents of /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: What's the content of /etc/network/interfaces ?

Comment: Without commenting on the strategy itself, don't use `sudo` in `/etc/rc.local`; it's run by init with privileges.  If you wish to test it, then use `sudo rc.local` instead.

Comment: @Domme I have added content of `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: Try this link : https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74593/wifi-not-working-on-fresh-install/105799#105799