# WiFi not working on fresh install

Tags: raspbian, wifi, hardware

I have had my Raspberry Pi for a few years now and today I went to do a fresh reinstall of Raspbian. I downloaded v2.4.4 of NOOBs and used that to install Raspbian. Everything installs nicely except now I am not able to connect to or even see any WiFi networks. In previous installs I just plugged in the dongle and it was able to search, but when I do it on this fresh install the following happens (I am using the GUI version of Raspbian):

- Light on the USB does start blinking. Will eventually stop after a few minutes.
- If I hover over the WiFi icon on the task bar it says:

  - eth0 Link is down
  - wlan0 Not associated
- If I click on the WiFi icon it will say "No wireless interfaces found"

From the Googling that I've done, these are some of the commands I have done to try and diagnose the problem:

```
lsusb
> Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adaptor
> ... other devices
```

The command `ifconfig` shows 3 sections, one each for `eth0`, `lo`, and `wlan0`. All the values (e.g. `RX packets`) show as 0. I am having to manually type out the results so haven't included them here as not sure if it's important.

The command `iwconfig` shows `no wireless extension` for the `eth0` and `lo` entries, but for `wlan0` it has more details. I can provide a photo of this if needed.

I'm at a loss really of what to do, as previously the WiFi has worked straight away. My Googling brings up results where people are not able to connect to a specific WiFi network, but I'm not able to view any and so I'm not sure if those results are relevant.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See the settings in the answer to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address/37921#37921 and also I had a similar problem on my Raspberry Pi 3 with built in WiFi due to someone had changed the `/etc/network/interfaces` by adding an `ifacd` after the `auto lo` directive. I commented the two added lines out and rebooted and WiFi then worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have checked what my version of the file contains and it was completely empty (only the commented section and the include). I copied in the settings from that post and restarted but I still have the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: When you use NOOBS, were you able to enable the WiFi and choose your access point? You mention a dongle. What is the actual hardware version of Raspberry Pi? And does your `/etc/network/interfaces` file end with the `auto lo` or do you have the additional `iface` directives from the posting? Mine does not have anything after the `auto lo`. And check the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file as well.

Comment: Hi, I haven't had a chance to try yet and won't for the next few days. When I try it out I will let you know. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Have you tried it now?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: Default Wifi Setting**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Edit the Interface file

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

Save the file. And type this command in terminal

`sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Edit the wpa_supplicant.conf file.

```
country=IN
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1 
network={
        scan_ssid=1
        ssid="Your Hidden SSID"
        psk="Your SSID's Password"
        }
```

Please enter your Hidden SSID and Your Wifi password in scan_ssid and ssid. Make sure your raspberry pi country location should be me mapped mention country location.

Reboot the system.

**Expected Output:**

It will connect to hidden ssid

**Method 2: Your Connecting to University or Organization Wifi**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Add the following:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=IN
network={
        ssid="XXXXXXXX"
        priority=1
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
        pairwise=CCMP
        auth_alg=OPEN
        eap=PEAP
        identity="18XXXXXXXX3"
        password=hash:d7XXXXXXXXXXXxXXXxce
        phase1="peaplabel=0"
        phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

Save the file and exit the wpa_supplicant.conf. Your need to give your hidden wifi name in place of ssid, user ID in place of identity and Password need to converted into hash code format.

Use this command in terminal to convert your password into hash code format.

```
echo -n 'YOUR_REAL_PASSWORD' | iconv -t utf16le | openssl md4 > hash.txt
```

Next Do the following:

1. sudo nano hash.txt
2. Insert hash: in place of (stdin)=
3. Copy the entire text and exit
4. Next modify the password in wpa_supplicant.conf file and exit

Reboot the system.

**Expected Output:**

It will connect to hidden ssid

Comment: /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf is not a text file

Comment: Also, what if the WiFi net is *not* DHCP and requires a (manually entered) static IP? What changes should we do to the 2 files?